# Creating popup images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have multiple images on the same page have the ability to open a larger version, but every image only opens the last image specified in the code, not each individual one.

That's probably the worst way I could've worded it so hopefully the example code is easier to understand.

```css
#check:checked ~ label #cover {
  display: block;
}
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 435px;
  height: 585px;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  background-color: white;
}
#imgpre {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#imgpre:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display:none;">
<label for="check">
  <img id="imgpre" src="example1preview.png" />
</label>
<label for="check">
  <div id="cover">
    <div id="box">
      <img src="example1.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display:none;">
<label for="check">
  <img src="example2preview.png" />
</label>
<label for="check">
  <div id="cover">
    <div id="box">
      <img src="example2.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using duplicate html ids (check, cover, box, imgpre).
IDs are unique in html and must not be used more then once.

As you click on the first label with `for="check"` it will activate the same input as the second label with `for="check"` does. Therefore you see the same popup image for both inputs.

Use different IDs for the input elements and switch over to using `class` for `cover`, `box` and `imgpre` in your html and css.

BTW: You should use javascript to get this running. Using a hidden checkbox (which means multiple can be active at once) is not a good idea. There are plenty of JavaScript libraries which do exactly what u want (e.g http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

```css
.checkbox:checked ~ label .cover {
  display: block;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 435px;
  height: 585px;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  background-color: white;
}
.imgpre {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.imgpre:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="checkbox" style="display:none;">
<label for="check1">
  <img class="imgpre" src="example1preview.png" />
</label>
<label for="check1">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="example1.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="checkbox" style="display:none;">
<label for="check2">
  <img class="imgpre" src="example2preview.png" />
</label>
<label for="check2">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="example2.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```